# jQuery check if an input is type checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'd like to find out if an input is a checkbox or not, and the following doesn't work:

```
$("#myinput").attr('checked') === undefined
```

Thank you once again!

Answer (score 360, accepted):

You can use the pseudo-selector `:checkbox` with a call to jQuery's `is` function:

```
$('#myinput').is(':checkbox')
```

Comment: This is the method I always use.

Comment: You really can't get any simpler than that.

Comment: Why use the selector engine for this? It's completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Tim Down I take your point that there might be more efficient ways to accomplish the same thing.  I suppose I like this version because the code is very readable.

Comment: @KenBrowning: Fair enough. I was fairly anti-jQuery in 2009, particularly the prevalent SO attitude of blindly using jQuery for everything; my views have mellowed a bit since and I'd undo my downvote if it were possible. However, I still think I had a point. Alternative (which I can't deny is more verbose): `var myInput = $("myinput")[0]; var isCheckbox = myInput.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "input" && myInput.type == "checkbox";`

Comment: Despite it is uneficcient comparing to any clean JavaScript solution, it's still executing faster than You can blink our eye and this is the shortest solution. I believe that until there is no difference in execution time, You can stay with shortest and unefficient method.

Answer (score 23):

```
>>> a=$("#communitymode")[0]
<input id="communitymode" type="checkbox" name="communitymode">
>>> a.type
"checkbox"
```

Or, more of the style of jQuery:

```
$("#myinput").attr('type') == 'checkbox'
```

Comment: Perfectly valid. Not the simplest.

Comment: It saves using jQuery's selector engine, the use of which here is completely inappropriate. The first variant is much the better, since avoids any possibility of jQuery's confused `attr()` function messing anything up.

Comment: @Tim Down is right--you should change `attr()` to `prop()`, afaik. `attr()` doesn't always get the "real" attribute value (i.e. checked or not) from the browser. Honestly not sure why this is the case, but I learned this a while back.

Comment: In Chome, your second example is case sensitive: http://jsfiddle.net/gtza0uuL/. It is not with .prop, but I don't know if that can be gauranteed. Note: you can't just do .toLowerCase() either because 'type' may be undefined.

Answer (score 14):

```
$("#myinput").attr('type') == 'checkbox'
```

Answer (score 6):

A non-jQuery solution is much like a jQuery solution:

```
document.querySelector('#myinput').getAttribute('type') === 'checkbox'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this function:

```
function is_checkbox(selector) {
    var $result = $(selector);
    return $result[0] && $result[0].type === 'checkbox';
};
```

Or this jquery plugin:

```
$.fn.is_checkbox = function () { return this.is(':checkbox'); };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#myinput').is(':checkbox')
```

this is the only work, to solve the issue to detect if checkbox checked or not. It returns true or false, 
I search it for hours and try everything, now its work 
to be clear I use EDG as browser and W2UI

Comment: Remember use code refactor when you paste code in your questions and answers.